# wondering about libusb_bulk_transfer error code

Tags: return, libusb

```
libusb_open(device, &deviceHandle);
```

> returns 0

but

```
libusb_bulk_transfer(deviceHandle, 0x81, data1, 512, &len, 0);
```

> return -5

so I try to find error `code -5` using `printf`

```
LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE
LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW
LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
LIBUSB_TRANSFER_ERROR
LIBUSB_ERROR_INTERRUPTED
LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS
LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY
LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_MEM
LIBUSB_ERROR_COUNT
LIBUSB_ERROR_INVALID_PARAM
```

But none... and can't find anywhere in google...

What's the meaning of `error code -5` in `libusb_bulk_transfer`?

Help me!

Answer (score 7):

LibUSB error codes can be found in the libusb documentation, which is available online [here](https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/group__libusb__misc.html).

The functions `libusb_error_name` and `libusb_strerror` can also be used to get a string corresponding to the error code.
`-5` is `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND` : Entity not found.

Google suggest checking that you have successfully claimed the interface (you must claim the interface you want to use, with [`libusb_claim_interface`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga32fabedf5f13fdecf1cb33acdb19b57a) before doing IO).

Comment: I Really Apreciate it!! that's the what i find!