# 'LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND' error when calling libusb_bulk_transfer or libusb_interrupt_transfer

Tags: c, usb, libusb, low-level

I'm trying to communicate with a midi device. When using `libusb_bulk_transfer` or `libusb_interrupt_transfer`, I get a -5 error (`Entity not found`).

Theres two other questions describing my problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403994/wondering-about-libusb-bulk-transfer-error-code/24406137) and [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729045/how-to-fix-libusb-error-not-found-error-when-calling-libusb-bulk-transfer)), both tell me to claim the interface before using it.

The problem is that I'm on windows, and that function (`libusb_claim_interface`) isn't availible in Windows. It returns -12, which means `Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform`, same goes for detach_kernel_driver and other things like that.

What could be the reason of that error code and how can I fix it?

I added a "minimal reproducible example" although you probably don't have the same device and drivers I do : https://github.com/Guigui220D/libusb-zig-problem.

Comment: Probably hard to say without a [mcve] of how you opened a device and called that function.  Unless the answer is as simple as the fact that the functionality you need really isn't implemented for Windows, like the error message says.

Comment: I made this repository for the minimal code example. I doubt you can reproduce it, because you probably don't have the device I have nor the same drivers if you do (libusb). I forgot to precise that, by "that function" I meant libusbb_claim_interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a suggestion. Have you tried installing libusb for your device using zadig? If a system driver is already attached to the device libusb may have trouble connecting.

Comment: Yes, I've tried every driver in Zadig, and they all result in the same thing. The default system driver just doesn't allow me to even open the device, so I had no choice anyway. That's not a solution to the question, but I decided to use the windows midi api to directly receive midi events.